# lubridate 1.7.3 error: CCTZ: Unrecognized timezone of the input vector: ""

Tags: r, timezone, lubridate

I have just installed the latest version of lubridate (1.7.3) and am getting the following error

```
> x <- as.POSIXct("2014-06-01 08:21:59 BST")
> for (j in 1:1e4){
     dum <- lubridate::force_tz(x, tzone = 'UTC')
 }
> for (j in 1:1e8){
     dum <- lubridate::force_tz(x, tzone = 'UTC')
 }
Error in C_force_tz(time, tz = tzone, roll) : 
  CCTZ: Unrecognized timezone of the input vector: ""
> j
[1] 580
```

Strange that if I continue with `1e4` after the first loop I don't get it, and if I start with `1e8` I don't get it. Any ideas?

Comment: I can also reproduce this using your code.  R3.4.4 , lubridate - 1.7.3

Comment: I believe this issue was solved in this [commit](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/commit/c4636354e72ce1e6c427784cca94292b58a9271b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been resolved in the github version of lubridate https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/commit/c4636354e72ce1e6c427784cca94292b58a9271b.

They are hoping to release the fix this week

Comment: A new version of lubridate (1.7.4) has now been released with a fix for this

Answer (score -1):

I tried doing this exactly the way you said it, and the loop wouldn't even go through all `1e8` of the values without crashing my machine (which is pretty powerful, so that was a surprise). Also, I noticed that the original `dum` that was produced only had one date, and the rest were `NA`.

Will this do the same thing you need? I am guessing that you need to initialize a vector with `Date` objects. It worked very quickly for me:

```
> dum <- rep(lubridate::force_tz(x, tzone = 'UTC'),100000000)
> str(dum)
   POSIXct[1:100000000], format: "2014-06-01 08:21:59" "2014-06-01 08:21:59" "2014-06-01 08:21:59" "2014-06-01 08:21:59" ...
> system.time(rep(lubridate::force_tz(x, tzone = 'UTC'),100000000))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.31    0.24    0.55
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the above is just to try and get a reproducable example of what I think is a bug in lubridate, I don't actually need to run the above. But it sounds like you didn't get the same error but it just didn't finish going through the loop? For me it crasged quite soon after starting the `1e8` loop